# Use Serial Port as Digital Out

Tags: serial-port, ttls

I want to output a single bit from a program on my PC to a TTL circuit.

I know I can buy a digital I/O card, but I just want a single value.

Can I use one of the pins on the serial port as a single TTL out bit?

Edit: I can use Linux or Windows.

Comment: http://www.ktverkko.fi/~msmakela/electronics/relay/index.en.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can but you will need to do some level conversion as the output lines (like RTS) are not at TTL levels.

[Wiring and programming info here](http://www.beyondlogic.org/serial/serial1.htm#41)

[PC 9-pin wiring here](http://pinouts.ru/SerialPorts/Serial9_pinout.shtml)

[Level converter circuit here](http://dave.fraildream.net/micro/periph/232-ttl.html) - this circuit ("Common TTL serial interface") converts the Txd and Rxd lines to/from RS232 levels but if you just want to implement a single handshake line, use the circuitry for the PC's Txd line only (pin 3 on 9-pin connector) but connect it to the DTR (Pin 4 on 9-pin connector) or RTS (pin 7) line.

[VB code and example here](http://www.codeworks.it/net/VBNetRs232.htm)

Answer (score 2):

[This USB device](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) appears as a serial port to the OS so can easily be driven, and there are 3.3V and 5V versions.